# Can we find a simple basis for the cokernel of this derivation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-algebra

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero. Let $R$ be the $K$-algebra $K[x_0,x_1,\ldots]$ of polynomials in countably infinitely many variables.
Consider the $K$-linear derivation $\delta:R\to R$ following the Leibniz rule $\delta(ab)=\delta(a)\cdot b+a\cdot \delta(b)$ for all $a,b\in R$ as well as the rules
$\delta(x_i)=x_{i+1}$ for all $i=0,1,2,\ldots$.

> Can we find a nice basis (= a basis consisting of cosets of some monomials) for the cokernel $R/\delta(R)$?

A physicist friend asked me this question. I thought about it for a while, and made the following observation. Consider a monomial $M=\prod_{j=0}^n x_j^{a_j}$ with $a_n>0$. Then (w.r.t. the ordering where the highest appearing index dominates) the leading term of $\delta(M)$ has the form $a_n(M/x_n)x_{n+1}$. Observe that the exponent of $x_{n+1}$ is necessarily $1$. This lead us to make a conjecture:

> Let $S$ be the set of monomials $M=\prod_{j=0}^n x_j^{a_j}, a_j\in\Bbb{N}$ for all $j$, $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, $a_n>1$ together with all the monomials $x_0^i, i=0,1,\ldots$. Then the cosets $p+\delta(R)$, $p\in S$, form a $K$-basis of the cokernel $R/\delta(R)$.

The intuition is, of course, that the monomials with highest index exponent $a_n=1$ can be reduced modulo $\delta(K[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}])$ in view of the first observation.

**Questions.**

1. Is this conjecture true? Or (well) known in an appropriate context?
2. Failing that, is there another easy to describe basis for the cokernel?
3. What buzzwords should we use when searching for more information on this theme?

Asking before I commence an effort to check whether the intuition holds water, and leads to a proof. The problem feels very natural, and I suspect the answer is known already.

Comment: I'm not conversant with the physics side of this. AFAICT the idea is that $x_0$ corresponds to a (quantum mechanical) field, $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ its higher order derivatives, and the attention to the cokernel comes from the fact that for the purpose of building a theory we can mod out $\delta(R)$.

Comment: The conjecture seems right, and the proof seems to be straightforward. You have to define carefully the order on monomials. Then proofs by contradiction should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct, and here is why.

A key property of $\delta$ is that it preserves the total degree (recall that the total degree of a monomial $x_0^{e_0}x_1^{e_1}\ldots x_n^{e_n}$ is $\sum_{k=0}^n e_k$). If we denote by $R_t$ (for $t\geq 0$) the subspace of $R$ generated by all the monomials of total degree exactly $t$, then $R$ is the direct sum of the $R_t$ and each $R_t$ is stable by $\delta$, so the study of $\delta$ on $R$ reduces to the study of $\delta$ on each $R_t$. From now on, we fix a $t\geq 0$ and restrict ourselves to $R_t$.

Let $\cal S$ be the subpace generated by $S \cap R_t$. Our goal is to show that any monomial $m\in R_t$ can be uniquely written $m=s+d$ with $s\in {\cal S}$, $d\in \delta R_t$.

**Uniqueness:** That's the easy part, we must show that ${\cal S} \cap \delta R_t =\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Let $d\in \delta R_t$ with $d\neq 0$. Then $d=\delta r$ for some nonzero $r\in R_t$. Let $n$ be the largest integer such that $x_n$ appears in $r$, i.e. the degree $d_n$ of $x_n$ in $r$ is positive. Then $d=\delta r$ contains one or several monomials of the form (monomial in $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$)$x_n^{d_n-1}x_{n+1}$ ; those monomials are not in $S$, so $d\not\in {\cal S}$.

**Existence:** For this part, as noted in a comment in the OP, we must be careful in the choice of a monomial ordering, as the obvious, easy choices don't work.

Let $m$ be a monomial in $R_t$. We can write $m=x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\ldots x_{i_t}$ with $i_1\leq i_2\leq \ldots \leq i_t$. For $2\leq k\leq t$, put $d_k=i_k-i_1$. Then all the $d_k$'s are nonnegative. Next, define

$$
\mu(m)=(d_2+d_3+\ldots+d_t,d_t,d_{t-1},\ldots,d_2,i_1) \tag{1}
$$

By construction, this $\mu(m)$ is in ${\mathbb N}^t$. Denote by ${\leq}_1$ the lexicographic (dictionary) order in ${\mathbb N}^t$, and let ${\leq}_2$ denote the well-ordering of monomials of $R_t$ define by $m {\leq}_2 m'$ iff $\mu(m) {\leq}_1 \mu(m')$.

We then show that each monomial $m$ is in ${\cal S}+\delta R_t$, by ${\leq}_2$-induction on $m$, or in other words by ${\leq}_1$-induction on $\mu(m)$.

Base case : the ${\leq}_1$ ordering in ${\mathbb N}^t$ starts with the initial segment  $\lbrace (0,0,\ldots,0,i) \rbrace$ for $i\in {\mathbb N}$, corresponding to the monomials $m_i=x_i^t$ for $i\in {\mathbb N}$.  When $t=1$ and $i>0$, this $m_i$ monomial can be decomposed as $m_i=0+\delta(x_{i-1})$, otherwise it is in $S$ and can therefore be decomposed as $m_i=m_i+\delta(0)$.

Induction step : suppose that there is a decomposition for all $m'$ such that $\mu(m') {\leq}_1 \mu(m)$. Write $m=x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\ldots x_{i_t}$ with $i_1\leq i_2\leq \ldots \leq i_t$. If $i_{t-1}=i_t$, then $m\in S$ and we are done. So we can assume $i_{t-1} < i_t$. Let $M=x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\ldots x_{i_{t-1}}x_{i_t-1}$. Let $d$ be the degree of $x_{i_t-1}$ in $M$, so that

$$
M=x_{i_1}x_{i_2} \ldots x_{i_{t-d}} (x_{i_t-1})^d \tag{2}
$$

It follows that

$$\delta(M)=\sum_{k=1}^{t-d} l_k +dm \tag{3}$$

where $l_k$ is the monomial defined by

$$
l_k = x_{i_1}\ldots x_{i_{k-1}}x_{i_k+1}x_{i_{k+1}}\ldots x_{i_{t}} \tag{4}
$$

From (3), we deduce $m=\delta(\frac{M}{d})-\frac{1}{d}\sum_{k=1}^{t-d}l_k$, so it will suffice to show that each $l_k$ is in ${\cal S}+\delta R_t$. By the induction hypothesis, it will suffice to show that $\mu(l_k) \lt_1 \mu(m)$ for each $k$.

Let $s$ be the largest integer $s\geq k$ such that $i_k=i_{k+1}=\ldots =i_{s}$. Then $s \lt t$, and we can write $l_k=x_{I_1}x_{I_2}\ldots x_{I_t}$, with $I_1\leq I_2\leq \ldots I_t$, with

$$
I_j=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
i_j, & \textrm{when} & j\not\in \lbrace s,t \rbrace, \\
i_j+1, & \textrm{when} & j = s, \\
i_j-1, & \textrm{when} & j = t.
\end{array}\right. \tag{5}
$$

Suppose first that $s>1$. Then $\mu(l_k)=(D_2+D_3+\ldots+D_t,D_t,D_{t-1},\ldots,D_2,I_1)$ where

$$
D_j=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
d_j, & \textrm{when} & j\not\in \lbrace s,t \rbrace, \\
d_j+1, & \textrm{when} & j = s, \\
d_j-1, & \textrm{when} & j = t.
\end{array}\right. \tag{6}
$$

In particular, the smallest index at which $\mu(l_k)$ and $\mu(m)$ differ is the second, and the corresponding coordinate in $\mu(l_k)$ is one less than in $\mu(m)$. So $\mu(l_k) \lt_1 \mu(m)$ as wished.

We are now left with the case $s=1$. In that case, $\mu(l_k)=(D_2+D_3+\ldots+D_t,D_t,D_{t-1},\ldots,D_2,I_1)$ where

$$
D_j=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
d_j-1, & \textrm{when} & j\not\in \lbrace 1,t \rbrace, \\
d_j+1, & \textrm{when} & j = 1, \\
d_j-2, & \textrm{when} & j = t.
\end{array}\right. \tag{7}
$$

In particular, the smallest index at which $\mu(l_k)$ and $\mu(m)$ differ is the first, and the corresponding coordinate in $\mu(l_k)$ is $t$ less than in $\mu(m)$. So $\mu(l_k) \lt_1 \mu(m)$ again, which finishes the proof.